# Нет анимации фрагмента при вызове onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-animation

Добавляю фрагменты стандартным образом, устанавливая кастомную анимацию.

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.add_fragment, R.anim.exit_fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .replace(R.id.container_settings, ChooseBlackContactsSettingsFragment.newInstance())
            .commit();
```

Анимация, когда мы движемся "вперед" по фрагментам отрабатывает идеально, но когда мы нажимаем кнопку "назад", вызывается `onBackPressed()` и фрагмент просто убивается, анимации не происходит. Где я неправ?

Необходимо вызывать метод `.remove(Fragment fragment)` для того, чтобы анимация сработала?

Answer (score 1):

Все логично, ведь когда вы удаляете Fragment, его Canvas уже становится недоступен - рисовать анимацию просто не где.
Как вариант, можно использовать **replace** вместо **remove** и использовать фрагмент-пустышку, на котором рисовать данную анимацию.